# Passing List Box Item To DoubleClick Event

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have these methods.  I can doubleclick an item in the Collection List View and the Double_Click method does fire and I get the message box.  What I can't figure out is how to pass in the item itself so that I can access the string value that is in the 'WWPN' column.  I want to pass that as a parameter to another method that does some searching. It is as simple as casting sender back to a list item or a port result?

```
  private void BrowseFlogiDatabase_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionWindow cw = new CollectionWindow(this.VirtualFabricList);

        GridView grid = new GridView();
        GridViewColumn FCPortColumn = new GridViewColumn();
        FCPortColumn.Header = "FC Port";
        FCPortColumn.Width = Double.NaN;
        FCPortColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("FCPort");

        GridViewColumn WWPNColumn = new GridViewColumn();
        WWPNColumn.Header = "WWPN";
        WWPNColumn.Width = Double.NaN;
        WWPNColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("WWPN");

        GridViewColumn FCIDColumn = new GridViewColumn();
        FCIDColumn.Header = "FCID";
        FCIDColumn.Width = Double.NaN;
        FCIDColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("FCID");

        GridViewColumn SwitchNameColumn = new GridViewColumn();
        SwitchNameColumn.Header = "SwitchName";
        SwitchNameColumn.Width = Double.NaN;
        SwitchNameColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("SwitchName");

        grid.Columns.Add(FCPortColumn);
        grid.Columns.Add(WWPNColumn);
        grid.Columns.Add(FCIDColumn);
        grid.Columns.Add(SwitchNameColumn);

        cw.CollectionListView.View = grid;
        ObservableCollection<PortResult> flogidatabase = new ObservableCollection<PortResult>();

        var cs = this.switchList.Where(c => c.switchName == this.ProcessedSwitchesListView.SelectedItem.ToString());
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, FCPort> portpair in cs.FirstOrDefault().FlogiDatabase)

        {
            PortResult pr = new PortResult();
            pr.WWPN = portpair.Key.ToUpper();
            pr.FCPort = portpair.Value.ToString();



            pr.FCID = portpair.Value.WWPNList.Where(w => w.WWPNValue == pr.WWPN).Select(t => t.FCIDValue).FirstOrDefault().ToString();

            pr.SwitchName = cs.FirstOrDefault().switchName;
            flogidatabase.Add(pr);
        }


        cw.CollectionListView.ItemsSource = flogidatabase;

        FlogiAddDoubleClickEventStyle(cw, new MouseButtonEventHandler(FlogiDB_MouseDoubleClick));
        cw.Show();

    }


private void FlogiDB_MouseDoubleClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        MessageBox.Show("FlogiDatabase DoubleClick");
    }
```

Comment: I have figured out that I can cast sender as a System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem but I still can't figure out how to get to the values in it.  System.Windows.Forms also has a ListViewItem that contains SubItems.  Most of the examples use that, but the ListViewItem I am using doesn't have that attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer.   I need to access the DataContext property of the ListViewItem.  Given from the above code:

```
ObservableCollection<PortResult> flogidatabase = new ObservableCollection<PortResult>();
CollectionWindow cw = new CollectionWindow(this.VirtualFabricList);
cw.CollectionListView.ItemsSource = flogidatabase;
```

Then to get to what's stored in each ListViewItem we cast the DataContext back to a PortResult:

```
PortResult pr = ((PortResult)lvi.DataContext);
```

And we can then access the attributes in a PortResult.

```
string wwpn = pr.WWPN;
```